# Using link_to to submit form in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form like this:

```
<%= form_for @isbn, url: { controller: 'ads', action: 'new' }, method: 'get' do |f| %>
   ...
   <%= f.text_field(:value, placeholder: 'Type ISBN') %>
<% end %>
```

How would I go about creating a link_to with a pre-defined ISBN-num value, so that is submitted directly to my new action.

I have tried

```
<%= link_to 'Sell this book', sell_book_path(current_user.id, value: book.isbn) %>
```

Route:

```
sell_book GET    /users/:id/sell_book(.:format)        ads#new
```

... but the value doesn't seem to get passed to the controller action.

Thanks for any help! :)

URL when submitting the form (book showing up correctly and ad is ready to be created):

```
.../users/7/sell_book?utf8=%E2%9C%93&isbn%5Bvalue%5D=9781449382674
```

URL when using the link_to (failing):

```
.../users/7/sell_book?value=9780321573513
```

EDIT:

Got it working :) did:

```
<%= link_to 'Sell this book', sell_book_path(current_user.id, :isbn => { :value => book.isbn }) %>
```

Thanks to all who responded :)

Comment: you should `POST` to a `#create` action

Comment: Do you want to add a pre-filled value to a form?

Comment: @waco, actually I'm calling a #new action. My bad..

Comment: this right name on your `controller: 'ads'`?

Comment: @Ari yes, the link_to is displayed on each book in a list of book ads, so that a user can easily choose to sell a similar book if he/she owns that particular book

Comment: @Monk_Code, yes, that is the right name

Comment: So, `params[:value]` doesn't return anything for you within the `sell_book` action?

Comment: @PinnyM correct!:) I have updated my question containing the different URLs generated by form and link

Comment: GOT IT WORKING! Updated my question.. Sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: Note that the original form will pass the value back to be retrieved as `params[:isbn][:value]`, while the link method should be retrieved by `params[:value]`.  You are aware of this?

Comment: @PinnyM that was the problem! :) Got it working by :isbn => { :value => book.isbn } in the link_to :)